# How to fix "Laravel redirect to the same login page" and middleware return false all time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Work in the server (same code) but in localhost, it returns false always I have tried many ways.

I have tried Laravel build-in function login and so far the result always returns false while debugging.

```
//Middleware RedirectIfAdmin
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $auth=Auth::guard('admin');
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I will add other code also if needed please tell me I am a new to ask question here. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code from where you are calling the method handle?

Comment: I have came to know that it throw TokenMismatchException search for a long time I cannot solve that

Comment: Are you using in your login form {!! csrf_field() !!}  
or
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> ?

Answer (score 0):

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;



use Closure;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   class RedirectIfAdmin
     {
      public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
       {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```